# Silverlight MediaElement position weird behavior

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to do Frame-by-frame navigation in SL.
So far, I have succeeded in doing it using Ticks.
But I have noticed that if I add constant ticks to the mediaelement position, and then remove the SAME ticks value, I get different position.

For instance:

```
MoviePlayer.Position = MoviePlayer.Position.Add(getFrameDuration());
var X = MoviePlayer.Position.Ticks;
MoviePlayer.Position = MoviePlayer.Position.Substract(getFrameDuration());
var Y = MoviePlayer.Position.Ticks;
```

X does not equal Y.

How can this be??

```
private TimeSpan getFrameDuration()
{
    return new TimeSpan((int)Math.Round(1000 / 29.97* 10000));
}
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting of code by prefixing 4 spaces to each line instead of using the quote style.

Answer (score 0):

To get a good answer you need to post the code of the `getFrameDuration` method.

My bet is that getFrameDuration() returns `0`.

**EDIT**

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> If the media does not support seek operations (which is the case for
>   live streaming media), setting this property will have no effect on
>   media playback. Check the value of CanSeek before attempting to set
>   Position.
>
> If Position is settable, then the following run-time value constraints
>   apply:
>
> If Position is set to a negative value, the value will revert to a
>   TimeSpan with value 0:0:0.
>
> If Position is set to a value larger than the media's NaturalDuration,
>   then the NaturalDuration is set as Position

Comment: No. it returns constant all the time. I modified my answer.

Comment: I even tried to add and substract 10,000 all the time. and it didn't return right

Comment: @ Himberjack, I eddited my answer, did you check the CanSeek property and the NaturalDuration?

Comment: Again, this is not my problem. I can seek well in general. also frames. But when checking the accuracy, if the Ticks of the position is X and I add it 10000, its X + 10000, then , if I substract 10000 I don't get X, i get X + Y